# Multiple inputs in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, read-host

I have script where I ask for the user ID and I use `$userName` in all my commands.

Now I would like to also have the option to enter the PC name and turn back to the user ID, (if the user ID cannot be found it displays a custom error message). The problem is that `$userName` is unique and should contain the user ID and not the PC name. Side-note: PC names are imported with a CSV file.
Also all pc names are starting with BN.

```
Do {

# Check if a username is entered on the command prompt
Do {
    Write-Host "Enter the user ID: " -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
    $userName = Read-Host
} Until ($userName)

# Check if the user exists in Active Directory
$user = $(
         try {
                Get-ADUser -Server domainlocal -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$userName'"
         }
         catch {
                $null
         }
   )

# Output the result for the check in Active Directory
If (!$user) {
    Write-host  "The user does not exist, please try again."   -ForegroundColor Red 
} 
Else {
    Write-host "User found in Active Directory, loading options..." -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
    ''
}} Until ($user)
```

To get the user ID with the PC name it should be like this:

```
write-host "enter PC Name" 
$PCnaming = Read-Host

$userName = $Computernames.Where({$_. "PC name" -like $PCnaming })."User ID"

$userName
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Mathias, I want the option to put in the user ID or the PC name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the user to prefix PC names with something that'll allow you to distinguish it from a user ID:

```
Do {
    Write-Host "Enter the user ID (or enter a computer name prefixed with 'PC:'): " -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
    $userName = Read-Host
    if($userName -like 'PC:*'){
        $PCnaming = $userName -replace '^PC:'
        $userName = $Computernames.Where({$_. "PC name" -like $PCnaming })."User ID"
    }
} Until ($userName)
```

If the user enters `someusername` it'll be stored in `$userName`, but if the user enter `pc:computername`, the loop will attempt to extract the user ID associated with `computername`

Comment: Thanks that will do it!